# VB webbrowser control will not load HTTPS pages

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, https, webbrowser-control

I put together a simple little program for my own personal use in VB2010 that uses an embedded webbrowser control, that allows me to click through pre-selected websites one at a time. It's something I have been using for years with no problem.

Apparently one of the websites which contains a number of pages that I view daily has switched to HTTPS format, and the webbrowser control just says `The website cannot display the page.` None of the other pages are secure, so I am assuming that this is what's causing the problem. The pages will come up fine on a regular web browser, like IE or Firefox; just not in my embedded web browser.

A Google search for this problem has turned up nothing.

The emulation mode is set to IE11 edge mode through the registry key, but I have also tried setting it for standard IE11, with no change.

What needs to be done to allow secure pages for this simple application?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share this site address? Btw, you shouldn't modify the registry of a user, causing a system-wide modification, for your own app sake. It's also not necessary; you just need to `.Write` into the WebBrowser control document this line when you initialize it (`WebBroser1.Navigate("")`): `<meta http-equiv='x-ua-compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1'>`

Comment: @Jimi One of the sites is a comics site: https://www.gomics.com

Comment: I can't connect to the address you posted (`https://www.gomics.com/`).

Comment: @Jimi I'm terribly sorry. Typo. it's https://www.gocomics.com

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce the problem. The Web pag comes up (mostly) fine. Tested in VS 2017, FW 4.7.1 (but, AFAIK, the WebBrowser control has not been updated recently). The message `The website cannot display the page.` came out with the wrong site address, though.

Comment: @jimi Thanks for your help. It is apparently a moot point now. I just tried it again and it worked fine. I guess it was a problem on the server side that got fixed. Weird. Thanks again!